# What do I need to run to undo an alias a bash script made?

Tags: macos, bash, mamp

I usually use the mamp server on my Mac, but yesterday I ran this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

WWW_BASE='/Library/WebServer/Documents'
TARGET="$WWW_BASE"

expand_dir () {
  pushd "$1" >/dev/null
  DIR="`pwd`"
  popd >/dev/null
}

expand_dir `dirname $0`

clear

if [ -e "$WWW_BASE"/orbit ]; then
    echo 'Nothing to be done - linked already.'
else
    echo "Going to add link in $TARGET - 'sudo' may ask you for your password."

    ln -s "$DIR"/server/www/orbit $TARGET

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'Done.'
    else
        echo 'Failed (not an admin user or failed to authenticate).'
    fi
fi

echo
read -n 1 -s -p 'Press any key to continue...'
echo
```

How to undo this script I cant run my default server and all my aliases does not work any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script could only create symbolic link `/Library/WebServer/Documents/orbit` which points to `$DIR/server/www/orbit` where `$DIR` (`expand_dir` function populates this variable) is a directory location of a script at the time of execution. By removing said link named **`/Library/WebServer/Documents/orbit`** you should undo the effects of the script.